# Calculate the correlation coefficient using the probability density in Matlab

Tags: matlab, statistics, probability-density

I'm trying to use Matlab to calculate the correlation coefficient for a bidimensional normal law.

```
mu = [1 2]; 
SIGMA = [9 4; 4 3]; 
X = mvnrnd(mu,SIGMA); 
p = mvnpdf(X,mu,SIGMA);
```

The variable p stores the probability density of the vector X that follows the bidimensional normal law. I must use the probability function p to calculate the correlation coefficent and the function R = corrcoef(X) doesn't do that.

Comment: Not sure between which things you are trying to calculate the correlation, but `corrcoef` calculates the correlation between the columns of your matrix.

Comment: The correlation coefficient for the distribution is a function of the covariance (SIGMA here), so you can calculate that without generating any random numbers. Maybe you'll have to explain what you're trying to accomplish more clearly.

Answer (score 0):

You are actually creating one multivariate normal random number (1x2) in the third line of your code, but you need more.

According to the documentations:

**R = corrcoef(X)** returns a matrix **R** of correlation coefficients calculated from an input matrix **X** whose *rows are observations* and whose *columns are variables*.

in your case you have one observation and two variables, for which the **corrcoef** function will return 1.

so you can do something like this:

```
mu = [1 -1]; 
SIGMA = [.9 .4; .4 .3]; 
X = mvnrnd(mu,SIGMA,10); % a 10 x 2 matrix
p = mvnpdf(X,mu,SIGMA);  % a 10 x 1 vector

corrcoef(X)
ans =

    1.0000    0.7846
    0.7846    1.0000
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, I saw that the correlation coefficient was 1 when tested it. So the p variable has no actual use?